# Creating a global variable in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Vue.js 0.12, it was easy enough to pass a variable from the root component all the way down to its children: you just use `inherit: true` on any component that requires the data of its parent.

Vue.js 1.0 removed the ability to use `inherit: true`. Understandably, you really shouldn't be inheriting everything everywhere all the time.

This is something of a problem upgrading from 0.12 to 1.0 however. I've got components littered with `inherit`, most only so that it can get the important config variable `baseurl` from the root component. Such a variable should definitely by known by any component that has a link in it.

`<a href="{{ baseurl }}/page">Link</a>`

I *could* pass the prop for config to every single component, but that really seems redundant and clunky.

`<c0 :config="{baseurl: 'example.com'}"></c0>`

`<c1 :config="config"></c1>`

`<c2 :config="config"></c2>`

`<c3 :config="config"></c3>`

Any good way to create a global scope for all components?

Answer (score 5):

This might not be the best solution out there, but it works and isn't too much trouble. I just set a getter prototype method.

```
Vue.prototype.$config = function (key) { 
  var config = this.$root.$get('config');

  if (config) {
    return config[key];
  } 

  return '';
}
```

`<a href="{{ $config('baseurl') }}/page">Link</a>`

Accessible by any component.

Comment: Good solution!  You can also check out `vuex` for application-wide data management https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/

Comment: how could we define those config variables then?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using something like webpack in your Vue setup, then you can share a variable across your project with [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) / import statements.

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import config from './config.js'
import thing from './thing.js'

config.setColor('green');

var vm = new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   components: { thing },
   template: '<thing></thing>'
});
```

config.js:

```
var color = 'blue';

export default {
   getColor: function () {
      return color;
   },
   setColor: function (val) {
      color = val;
   }
}
```

thing.js:

```
import config from './config.js'

export default {
   name: 'thing',
   template: '<div>thing</div>',
   created: function () {
      console.log(config.getColor());
      // green
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy. All you need to do is to set it in the "data" area in your "main.js" file. I am not sure why all other answers are complicating things.

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    API: "http://localhost:8080"
  },
  router,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

And then in any component, you access it through "this.$root"

```
console.log(this.$root.API);
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at : [vue-config](https://github.com/airyland/vue-config)

```
npm install vue-config

const vueConfig = require('vue-config')
const configs = {
  API: 'http://localhost:6003' // It's better to require a config file
}

Vue.use(vueConfig, configs)

// A param named `$config` will be injected in to every 
// component, so in your component, you can get config easily
const API = this.$config.API
```

vuex may be too heavy for defining constant.  however, once your problem solved, you must take a look at [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/).