# how to access (build time) config variables client side?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, config

I'm using a vueJS boilerplate, which has various settings in a `/config` directory that are used at build time.

I'm wondering if there is a convention for how these are available client side too? Of course this depends on the boilerplate. I don't see anything setting this up, so I guess I have to create my own API to pass this from client to server.

Alternately is there a convention for including some current config settings into a client side file? I really want to just display some things like the NODE_ENV and other build time settings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign its value to `data` then render it in client-side

```
<div>{{ NODE_ENV }}</div>


data() {
  return {
    NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV
  }
}
```

Comment: is `process` available client side? that looks like server side code.

Comment: No. `process` is only available in node env. But in this code, Webpack will replace `process.env.NODE_ENV` with current `NODE_ENV` value and it will work in client-side too

Comment: how does webpack know to replace that in a client file? is there a webpack spec required somewhere that any instance of a specific string should be replaced at build time? Seems like a lot of weird magic to me.

Comment: There is a plugin called `DefinePlugin`: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/. And VueJS boilerplate uses it to set `process.env.NODE_ENV` value

Comment: so where does the code above go? Into a webpack config file somewhere? It looks like the standard vue client side `data()` method - it seems a lot of magic to suddenly include a specific `process.env.X` value in client code. Don't I need to also declare a headsup about that deep in webpack config somewhere?

Comment: Yes! You have to custom your webpack's config! Have you read the link I send?

Answer (score 0):

vue-config seems to be a good way to handle client side configs and can read config from an endpoint.

https://github.com/airyland/vue-config

from this question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42549522/1146785